# Laravel log write permission denied

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing permission issue with log writing in my laravel app. We have daily logs so a new log file gets created every day. The project folder ownership is set to `www-data`. And the logs are normally generated with `www-data` permission. But sometimes the logs are created with `root` user and then if somewhere I try to write in log I get permission denied and application crashes.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 77016 Sep 12 05:00 laravel-2017-09-11.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      1240 Sep 12 10:30 laravel-2017-09-12.log
```

For example, yesterday's log was created by `www-data` but today it's under `root`. So I am getting crashes everytime. If I delete the log or change the permission to `777` then it solves for a while until it pops up again. I cannot replicate the issue and don't know why logs are being created under root user. Any help would be appriciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a cron task which run with root privileges that logs into this application ?

Comment: Yes I do have cron tasks. And it logs too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run your cron as www-data user.

Ex: `* * * * * www-data php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`